# T-SQL CASE Clause: How to specify WHEN NULL

Tags: t-sql

I wrote a T-SQL Statement similar like this (the original one looks different but I want to give an easy example here):

```
SELECT first_name + 
    CASE last_name WHEN null THEN 'Max' ELSE 'Peter' END AS Name
FROM dbo.person
```

This Statement does not have any syntax errors but the case-clause always chooses the ELSE-part - also if the last_name is null. But Why?

What I want to do is to unite first_name and last_name, but if last_name is null the whole name becomes null:

```
SELECT first_name +
   CASE last_name WHEN null THEN '' ELSE ' ' + last_name END AS Name 
FROM dbo.person
```

Do you know where the problem is?

Answer (score 416, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN last_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' '+last_name END
```

Comment: @Luther's COALESCE suggestion is better than my answer. It's marginally less efficient, but much more elegant.

Comment: Handling it with something like this may be of use, or something of the like: 

    COALESCE(last_name, '')

The case statement, while concise, is imho less maintainable than COALESCE in large queries. In the end, you have the same result. If you need to optimize, check the execution plans but I have not noticed much of a difference.

Comment: `COALESCE` basically internally translates into `CASE` . The problem with CASE is that `last_name` is evaluated twice and it can lead to other side effects – see this excellent [article](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull). To solve what was asked, I would rather go with `ISNULL(' '+ last_name, '')` mentioned in [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237646/t-sql-case-clause-how-to-specify-when-null#comment3343348_3237704) below.

Answer (score 47):

The WHEN part is compared with ==, but you can't really compare with NULL. Try

```
CASE WHEN last_name is NULL  THEN ... ELSE .. END
```

instead or COALESCE:

```
COALESCE(' '+last_name,'')
```

(' '+last_name is NULL when last_name is NULL, so it should return '' in that case)

Comment: Okay thank you for the information with the == in the WHEN part. I didn't know that. With COALESCE it does also work fine. Haven't thought that there are so much possibilities to do that.

Comment: I feel the `' ' +` part is superfluous (and may hinder performance as it causes string copying).

Answer (score 20):

There are plenty of solutions but none covers why the original statement doesn't work.

```
CASE last_name WHEN null THEN '' ELSE ' '+last_name
```

After the when, there is a check for equality, which should be true or false.

If one or both parts of a comparison is null, the result of the comparison will be UNKNOWN, which is treated like false in a case structure. See: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/

To avoid this, Coalesce is the best way.

Answer (score 14):

Given your query you can also do this:

```
SELECT first_name + ' ' + ISNULL(last_name, '') AS Name FROM dbo.person
```

Comment: This adds a redundant space when last_name is null, which is what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: Better use `ISNULL(' '+ last_name, '')` to prevent the redundant space.

Comment: Yeah realized it after I posted.  Figured I'd leave it since it solved the part he was having trouble with.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that null is not considered equal to itself, hence the clause never matches.

You need to check for null explicitly:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN last_name is NULL THEN first_name ELSE first_name + ' ' + last_name
```

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
SELECT first_name + ISNULL(' '+last_name, '') AS Name FROM dbo.person
```

This adds the space to the last name, if it is null, the entire space+last name goes to NULL and you only get a first name, otherwise you get a firts+space+last name.

this will work as long as the default setting for concatenation with null strings is set:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
```

this shouldn't be a concern since the `OFF` mode is going away in future versions of SQl Server

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that NULL is not considered to be equal to anything even not to itself, but the strange part is that is also *not not* equal to itself.

Consider the following statements (which is BTW illegal in SQL Server T-SQL but is valid in My-SQL, however this is what ANSI defines for null, and can be verified even in SQL Server by using case statements etc.)

`SELECT NULL = NULL -- Results in NULL`

`SELECT NULL <> NULL -- Results in NULL`

So there is no true/false answer to the question, instead the answer is also null.

This has many implications, for example in

1. CASE statements, in which any null value will always use the ELSE clause unless you use explicitly the WHEN IS NULL condition (***NOT*** the `WHEN NULL` condition )
2. String concatenation, as
   `SELECT a + NULL -- Results in NULL`
3. In a WHERE IN or WHERE NOT IN clause, as if you want correct results make sure in the correlated sub-query to filter out any null values.

One can override this behavior in SQL Server by specifying `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, however this is *NOT* recommended and should not be done as it can cause many issues, simply because deviation of the standard.

(As a side note, in My-SQL there is an option to use a special operator `<=>` for null comparison.)

In comparison, in general programming languages null is treated is a regular value and is equal to itself, however the is the NAN value which is also not equal to itself, but at least it returns 'false' when comparing it to itself, (and when checking for not equals different programming languages have different implementations).

Note however that in the Basic languages (i.e. VB etc.) there is no 'null' keyword and instead one uses the 'Nothing' keyword, which cannot be used in direct comparison and instead one needs to use 'IS' as in SQL, however it is in fact equal to itself (when using indirect comparisons).

Comment: "The strange part is that is also not not equal to itself."  => this is not strange considering that null in SQL has the meaning   'unknown'.   Something unknown, is most likely not the same as something else that is unkown.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution to this. Just `ISNULL` the `CASE` statement:

```
ISNULL(CASE x WHEN x THEN x ELSE x END, '') AS 'BLAH'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE  
    WHEN last_name IS null THEN '' 
    ELSE ' ' + last_name 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

**When you get frustrated trying this:**

```
CASE WHEN last_name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' '+last_name END
```

**Try this one instead:**

```
CASE LEN(ISNULL(last_Name,''))
WHEN 0 THEN '' 
ELSE ' ' + last_name
END AS newlastName
```

`LEN(ISNULL(last_Name,''))` measures the number of characters in that column, which will be zero whether it's empty, or NULL, therefore `WHEN 0 THEN` will evaluate to true and return the '' as expected.

I hope this is a helpful alternative.

I have included this test case for sql server 2008 and above:

```
DECLARE @last_Name varchar(50) = NULL

SELECT 
CASE LEN(ISNULL(@last_Name,''))
WHEN 0 THEN '' 
ELSE 'A ' + @last_name
END AS newlastName

SET @last_Name = 'LastName'

SELECT 
CASE LEN(ISNULL(@last_Name,''))
WHEN 0 THEN '' 
ELSE 'A ' + @last_name
END AS newlastName
```

Comment: Are you sure that works? Most functions return NULL when given a NULL input and my tests confirm that's also true of LEN() i.e., LEN(NULL) returns NULL, not 0.

Comment: Pokechu22 is correct, and this is the corrected script:                                   CASE LEN(ISNULL(last_Name,''))
WHEN 0 THEN '' 
ELSE ' ' + last_name
END AS newlastName

Answer (score 1):

Jason caught an error, so this works...

Can anyone confirm the other platform versions?
SQL Server:

```
SELECT
CASE LEN(ISNULL(last_name,'')) 
WHEN 0 THEN '' 
ELSE ' ' + last_name
END AS newlastName
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT
CASE LENGTH(IFNULL(last_name,'')) 
WHEN 0 THEN '' 
ELSE ' ' + last_name
END AS newlastName
```

Oracle:

```
SELECT
CASE LENGTH(NVL(last_name,'')) 
WHEN 0 THEN '' 
ELSE ' ' + last_name
END AS newlastName
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried casting to a string and testing for a zero-length string and it worked.

```
CASE 
   WHEN LEN(CAST(field_value AS VARCHAR(MAX))) = 0 THEN 
       DO THIS
END AS field
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsNull function

```
select 
    isnull(rtrim(ltrim([FirstName]))+' ','') +
    isnull(rtrim(ltrim([SecondName]))+' ','') +
    isnull(rtrim(ltrim([Surname]))+' ','') +
    isnull(rtrim(ltrim([SecondSurname])),'')
from TableDat
```

if one column is null you would get an empty char

Compatible with Microsoft SQL Server 2008+

Answer (score 0):

Use the CONCAT function available in SQL Server 2012 onward.

```
SELECT CONCAT([FirstName], ' , ' , [LastName]) FROM YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL does not equal anything.  The case statement is basically saying when the value = NULL .. it will never hit.
There are also several system stored procedures that are written incorrectly with your syntax.  See sp_addpullsubscription_agent and sp_who2.
Wish I knew how to notify Microsoft of those mistakes as I'm not able to change the system stored procs.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017, Microsoft introduced a Concatenate With Separator function, for just your situation:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) FROM dbo.person
```

CONCAT_WS skips NULL values, but not empty strings.

Interestingly, MySQL introduced CONCAT_WS over a decade earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
CASE IsNull(last_name,'') WHEN '' THEN 'Max' ELSE 'Peter' END AS Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2022 you can use the `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` predicate (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) and you could re-write the OP's statement like so:

```
SELECT first_name +
   CASE when last_name is not distinct from null THEN '' ELSE ' ' + last_name END AS Name 
FROM dbo.person
```