# CASE is not working properly

Tags: sql-server

I have following two queries. The first query is straight forward and is working as epecte when @MyParam is null. But the second query is not returning the same result. What is the mistake in the second query.

Note: I have been asked to use the second approach since the client asked to get rid of “@MyParam IS NULL” check (used in query 1)

**QUERY**

```
DECLARE @MyParam INT

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (EmpID INT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (4)

--Query 1
SELECT * 
FROM @MyTable M
WHERE M.EmpID = @MyParam OR @MyParam IS NULL

-- Query 2 (Rewrite for performance)
SELECT * 
FROM @MyTable M
WHERE M.EmpID = (CASE @MyParam WHEN NULL THEN M.EmpID ELSE @MyParam END)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write

```
SELECT * 
FROM @MyTable M
WHERE M.EmpID = IsNULL(@MyParam,M.EmpID)
```

Or if you need to use `case`for some other reason

```
WHERE M.EmpID = (CASE WHEN @MyParam IS NULL THEN M.EmpID ELSE @MyParam END)
```

Case is working properly. Select is not broken. http://pragmatictips.com/26

Comment: Thanks. Marked as answer. I have a relaetd question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229937/rewriting-query-using-case-statement

Answer (score 0):

You should use IS NOT NULL. NEVER compare NULL with anything

```
NULL=NULL - > false
NULL <> NULL -> false
```

Comment: This is not always true.

Comment: the IS keyword is a comparer ...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
SELECT * 
FROM @MyTable M
WHERE M.EmpID = ISNULL(@MyParam, M.EmpID)
```

or if it's performance you seek, checking for `@MyParam` with an `IF` statement

```
IF @MyParam IS NULL THEN
  SELECT * FROM @MyTable
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM @MyTable WHERE EmpID = @MyParam
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `coalesce()` for this purpose.  It is the shorted, ANSI standard method:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM @MyTable m
WHERE m.EmpID = coalesce(@MyParam, m.EmpID);
```

Note that this logic is subtly different from the first method, in the case the m.EmpId is `NULL`.  The equivalent logic would be:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM @MyTable m
WHERE m.EmpID = coalesce(@MyParam, m.EmpID) or (m.EmpId is NULL and @MyParam is NULL);
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is `CASE WHEN @MyParam IS NULL THEN M.EmpID ELSE @MyParam END`

please see similar answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3237670/11436