# Rewriting query using CASE statement

Tags: sql-server

I need to rewrite the following tow queries to avoid OR @MyParam IS NULL check (by using CASE Statement as mentioned in [CASE is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229410/case-is-not-working-properly))

Is it possible to rewrite following queries in that format?

Note: The fn_Split function is available in [How to pass string parameter with `IN` operator in stored procedure SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872056/how-to-pass-string-parameter-with-in-operator-in-stored-procedure-sql-server-2)

```
DECLARE @MyParam VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @MyParam = '2,3'

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (EmpID INT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (4)


--Query 1
SELECT * 
FROM @MyTable M
WHERE (
        M.EmpID IN (SELECT CONVERT(int,Value) FROM fn_Split(@MyParam, ','))
        OR @MyParam IS NULL
       )


--Query 2
SELECT * 
FROM @MyTable M
WHERE (EXISTS   (
                  SELECT CONVERT(int,Value) 
                  FROM fn_Split(@MyParam, ',')
                  WHERE CONVERT(int,Value)  =  M.EmpID
                  )
                  OR @MyParam IS NULL
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM @MyTable M
    left join (SELECT CONVERT(int,Value) v FROM fn_Split(@MyParam, ',')) t 
on m.EmpID = t.v 
where v is not null or @MyParam is null
```

Ideally you wouldn't pass a string containing multiple values as a parameter - if this is a stored procedure, use a [table valued parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)