# How to replace NULL value in select with subquery

Tags: sql, db2

Hi I'm performing a left join on two tables. If a particular column is NULL I want to run a subquery to get a value from a completely different table. Here's what I have now:

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_NUM, A.USER_ID, 
   CASE B.PREFERRED_NAME
        WHEN '' THEN RTRIM(B.FIRST_NAME) || ' ' || B.LAST_NAME
        ELSE RTRIM(B.PREFERRED_NAME) || ' ' || B.LAST_NAME 
   END AS NAME
FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
```

`TABLE_B` sometimes doesn't contain a record that matches with `TABLE_A`, so I want to run a subquery from `TABLE_C` that contains usernames and will match on `A.USER_ID`.

I thought I could do something like:

```
CASE B.PREFERRED_NAME
     WHEN NULL THEN subquery here
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR [42703] [IBM][DB2] SQL0206N  "NULL" is not valid in the context where it is used.
```

Probably because NULLs are not allowed for that column.

**SOLVED**
Thanks for the help. This is how I solved my issue:

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_NUM, A.USER_ID, 
CASE 
    WHEN B.PREFERRED_NAME IS NULL THEN C.USER_ID
    WHEN B.PREFERRED_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN 
         CASE PREFERRED_NAME
         WHEN '' THEN RTRIM(B.FIRST_NAME) || ' ' || B.LAST_NAME
         ELSE RTRIM(B.PREFERRED_NAME) || ' ' || B.LAST_NAME 
         END
END AS NAME
FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
JOIN TABLE_C C
ON A.USER_ID = C.USER_ID
```

Comment: Not sure about the DB2 specifics. Did you try rewriting like `CASE 
WHEN B.PREFERRED_NAME = ''  THEN ... WHEN B.PREFERRED_NAME IS NULL THEN ...`? However, what exactly do you mean by "[...] because NULLs are not allowed for that column."

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL CASE Clause: How to specify WHEN NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237646/t-sql-case-clause-how-to-specify-when-null)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your query, you can probably just add your third table as another `LEFT JOIN`, then add the column you want to a `COALESCE` function:

Also, it looks like you're storing the preferred name as spaces if there isn't one, in which case you can use the `NULLIF` function to convert it to a `NULL`, which will work with your `COALESCE`.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
SELECT
     A.ACCOUNT_NUM
    ,A.USER_ID
    ,COALESCE(
         NULLIF(B.PREFERRED_NAME,'')
        ,B.FIRST_NAME
        ,C.OTHER_NAME
    ) || ' ' || B.LAST_NAME AS NAME
FROM TABLE_A A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_C C
  ON C.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B B
  ON A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
```

If you know there is always going to be a row in `C` that matches `A`, then you could convert that to a regular (inner) `JOIN`.

---

The reason you're getting the error, though is because you can't use `NULL` like that in a `CASE` statement. If you want to have a `NULL` case, then you have to do it like @Abecee said in the comment with `CASE WHEN B.PREFERRED_NAME IS NULL THEN ...`