# Testing for NULL in a CASE clause

Tags: sql, case

I'm confused as to why these two CASE statements provide different answers, when a DATETIME value is NULL.

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = NULL;
SELECT CASE ISNULL(@MyDate, 0)
    WHEN 0 THEN 'It Is Null'
    ELSE 'It Is a Date'
  END;
```

This results in the value 'It Is Null', which is straightforward - a NULL value is turned into 0, then we test for 0. However:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = NULL;
SELECT CASE @MyDate
    WHEN NULL THEN 'It Is Null'
    ELSE 'It Is a Date'
  END;
```

The above results in 'It Is a Date', which is my point of confusion. The clause will not accept "WHEN **IS** NULL" which is what I first thought was the problem.

Why won't CASE WHEN recognise a NULL value?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The case expression syntax you are using is comparing the value you provided in the `case` part to each of the values provided and the `when` parts (and stops once it found a match).
So what you are actually asking in that statement is `@Date = NULL` - that will always evaluate to false.
You can write it like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @MyDate IS NULL 
THEN  'It Is Null'
ELSE  'It Is a date'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry found the answer after I posted, which is here:

[T-SQL CASE Clause: How to specify WHEN NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237646/t-sql-case-clause-how-to-specify-when-null)

The syntax is just a little different to achieve the right result.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what RDBMS you are using but in T-SQL the correct (and the ANSI compliant overall) way to do it is:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = NULL;
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN @MyDate IS NULL 
    THEN 'It Is Null'
    ELSE 'It Is a Date'
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

An observation I've made recently: people get really confused about `CASE` expressions, whereas the equivalent construct using `UNION` is easy to write and understand (and seems to handle nulls more intuitively!) e.g.

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = NULL;
SELECT 'It Is Null'
 WHERE @MyDate IS NULL
UNION
SELECT 'It Is a Date'
 WHERE @MyDate IS NOT NULL;
```