# T-SQL CASE Clause: Issue on specifying WHEN NULL with an Outer JOIN

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Following query correctly displays all current/prospective customers' record regardless of whether an order was placed by him/her or not. But the `YesNO` alias of the `SELECT` statement below is always returning 1 even when in some cases `o.OrderID` is null (i.e., when a perspective customer has not placed an order yet). Why? I think the CASE statement below is correct (as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3237670/1232087) response as well). I'm using `SQL Server 2012`. **NOTE**: Please keep in mind that although the OrderID is a PK it will always be null along with all other columns of orders table in an OUTER JOIN if the join condition is not met.

```
SELECT c.customerID, o.OrderID, CASE When o.OrderID is NULL Then 0 Else 1 End as YesNO
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o
 ON c.customerID = o.customerID
```

Comment: Are you sure there are cases where the `o.OrderId` is null? Or is that supposed to be `c.OrderId`?

Comment: @DigiFriend Yes.That's why I'm including `o.OrderID` in `SELECT` so I could verify.

Comment: are u execute it under northwind database? your query is correct. if yes then it shows 0 properly

Comment: For 'FISSA' customerid orderid is null and it shows 0 on that row

Comment: If you are getting `1`, then `o.OrderID` is not `null`. Are you considering some other value to be `null` that isn't an actual `null` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ISNULL

I am pretty sure that the reason is because when you compare IS NULL to NULL the result is NULL, thus False, hence why it is evaluating to your ELSE 1

```
SELECT c.customerID, o.OrderID, CASE When ISNULL(o.OrderID, 0) = 0 Then 0 Else 
1 End as YesNO
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o
 ON c.customerID = o.customerID
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining a possible reason for the issue, as well.

Comment: When you check if a value `is null` it returns true or false, not `null`. When you try to check if a value is null by using `= null` *then* you would get `null`. Also, `null` does not mean false, but it does not mean true either and since it is not `true` then it would not return `0` per the `when ...`.