# Case statement to ISNULL

Tags: t-sql

I am very new to T-SQL and am looking to simplify this query using isnull.

```
case 
when datediff(d, appdate, disdate) IS NOT NULL THEN datediff(d, appdate, disdate) 
ELSE 
    Case 
        when appdate is null THEN datediff(d,update,getdate())
        when disdate IS NULL THEN datediff(d,appdate,getdate())
    END
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237646/t-sql-case-clause-how-to-specify-when-null

Comment: Tip: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at MSDN Blogs [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100715082018/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of a simplification but this should do the same thing:

```
ISNULL(datediff(d, appdate, disdate) , 
    CASE WHEN appdate IS NULL THEN datediff(d,update,getdate())
         WHEN disdate IS NULL THEN datediff(d,appdate,getdate()) END
)
```

Comment: The second argument to `ISNULL` could maybe be simplified a bit (to `datediff(DAY,IIF(appdate IS NULL,[update],appdate),getdate())`)

Comment: @MartinSmith I thought about it but since this is a `case when...when...` and not a `case when else` I figured it's not exactly equivalent and therefor I shouldn't use `IIF` in this case.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thank you very much for the idea. I used it and was able to narrow it down to:

isnull(datediff(d,appdate,disdate), isnull(datediff(d,appdate,getdate()), datediff(d,update,getdate())))

Comment: @MartinSmith I did not think about using IIF for this. This makes total sense. Thank you.