# Count number of null and not nulls in table

Tags: mysql

Here is my query. My table has only 4 rows right now. 3 of them have a UNIX timestamp in column `confirmed_at`, and 1 row is `null`

```
SELECT 
   date(`user`.`created_at`) AS `Date`, 
   SUM(case `user`.`confirmed_at` when null then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Null values',
   SUM(case `user`.`confirmed_at` when null then 0 else 1 end) AS 'Non-null values'
FROM `user`
GROUP BY date(`user`.`created_at`);
```

When i run this query, results shown are

```
Date      | Null Values | non-null values
1/12/2022 | 0           | 4
```

it should be

```
Date      | Null Values | non-null values
1/12/2022 | 1           | 3
```

can someone help me, not sure what i'm missing here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by adding `IS` when check if it's null or not,more details can be found at [**t-sql-case-clause-how-to-specify-when-null**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237646/t-sql-case-clause-how-to-specify-when-null)

```
SELECT 
   date(`user`.`created_at`) AS `Date`, 
   SUM(case `user`.`confirmed_at` when is null then 1 else 0 end) AS 'Null values',
   SUM(case `user`.`confirmed_at` when is null then 0 else 1 end) AS 'Non-null values'
FROM `user`
GROUP BY date(`user`.`created_at`);
```

Comment: also had to change `case `user`.`confirmed_at`` to `case when `user`.`confirmed_at``